# Flex 3.5 style individual buttons

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

If I have a button named:

```
<mx:Button id="backButton">
```

and another named:

```
<mx:Button id="cancelButton"
```

How can I style each button seperatly?

Can I give each button a style, then set the style in CSS... E.g.

```
Button #style {
  backgroundColor: red;
}
```

Comment: What does Button #style mean?

Comment: Well in CSS thats how you would apply a style to a button with an ID of style.

Comment: oh cool, i didn't know that. i used to just use class names like in the answer given below :)

Comment: In HTML CSS yes, this is not the same since the ids aren't exposed to the top layer, only to the class who contains it.

Answer (score 2):

In CSS:

```
.firstButton {
  backgroundColor: red;
}

.secondButton {
  backgroundColor: blue;
}
```

Buttons:

```
<mx:Button id="backButton" styleName="firstButton" />

<mx:Button id="cancelButton" styleName="secondButton" />
```